# plot crash r session with library emojifont

Tags: r, plot, emoji

When I load `library(emojifont)`, totally the following plot crashes my r session. This script worked a few months ago and the library has the same version. There is probably something with my own installation because the maintainer could not reproduce the problem ([as I posted an issue on github](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/emojifont/issues/8)). But I have no clues.
I work with Ubuntu 16.04. Library emojifont version 0.50.

> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
>   Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Indeed, I remarked the following behavior:

### Test 1

If I run the code in this order in a **new session**, the first plot is ok:

```
# Order 1 ----
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, cex=0)

library(emojifont)
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=1.5, col='steelblue', family='OpenSansEmoji')
```

[image: order_ok]
But, then, if I close the plot and draw a new one `plot(x, y, cex=0)` in the same session, the session crashes.

### Test 2

If, in a **new session**, I call the library before a plot, the call to a plot crashes directly the session, even without `emoji` inside:

```
# Order 2 ----
library(emojifont)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, cex=0)
# Dont have time to run this line, the session crashes
text(x, y, labels=emoji('cow'), cex=1.5, col='steelblue', family='OpenSansEmoji')
```

Error is the following:

> Erreur : C stack usage  140727315310780 is too close to the limit
>   De plus : Warning message:
>   In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : font family 'T??VUUUUU?%P?,@73@' not found, will use 'wqy-microhei' instead
>   Erreur :

[image: message_before_crash]

It seems that the font is not recognized but I tried directly installation the two font families on my computer and this did not change. By the way, if I only send `emoji('evergreen_tree')` in the console, it returns the emoji, which assumes that the font family is recognised:

```
[1] ""
```

I updated all my libraries and re-installed emojifont.
Is there anything in emojifont that modifies plotting behavior ? What in my installation can have changed to produce this problem ?

Comment: Bug reports should go to package maintainers: https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/emojifont/issues

Comment: Which is what I did, as I wrote in my question, but the maintainer closed the issue as he couldn't reproduce it. So I was hoping that anybody had a good idea about it. https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/emojifont/issues/8

Comment: What could have changed? Possibly your freetype installation.

Comment: Indeed, `libfreetype6` have been updated in May. I cannot go back to earlier version as it breaks a lot of dependencies. Using the appropriate ppa to install a newer version does not solve the problem. I will investigate further on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since library `libfreetype6-dev` in Ubuntu has been updated, it was necessary to reinstall library `emojifont`. However, you must also reinstall the libraries it depends on:

```
install.packages(c("sysfonts", "showtextdb", "showtext"))
install.packages("emojifont")
```

This solved the problem.
Thanks @Roland who showed me the direction.